# Get current playing file in MPlayer slave mode

Tags: mplayer, slave, ash

Problem: I can't find any way to reliably get the current playing file in an MPlayer playlist.

Here is how far I have gotten. This working ash script monitors a text file with the path to the current playlist. When I update the file, the script closes the old instance of MPlayer and opens a new one with the new playlist:

```
# POLL PLAYLIST FILE FOR CHANGES
CURRENTPLAYLISTPATH=/home/tc/currentplaylist
INFIFO=/tmp/mplayer-in

CURRENTPLAYLIST="NEVERMATCHAPLAYLIST"
FIRSTRUN=1

while [ 1 ];
do
    # CHECK FOR NEW PLAYLIST
    NEWPLAYLIST=$(head -n 1 $CURRENTPLAYLISTPATH)
    if [[ "$NEWPLAYLIST" != "$CURRENTPLAYLIST" ]]; then
        if [ "$FIRSTRUN" == 0 ]; then
            echo "quit" > "$INFIFO"
        fi

        # CREATE NAMED PIPE, IF NEEDED
        trap "rm -f $INFIFO" EXIT
        if [ ! -p $INFIFO ]; then
            mkfifo $INFIFO
        fi

        # START MPLAYER
        mplayer -fixed-vo -nolirc -vc ffmpeg12vdpau,ffh264vdpau, -playlist $NEWPLAYLIST -loop 0 -geometry 1696x954 -slave -idle -input file=$INFIFO -quiet -msglevel all=0 -identify | tee -a /home/tc/mplayer.log &

        CURRENTPLAYLIST=$NEWPLAYLIST
        FIRSTRUN=0
    fi

    sleep 5;
done
```

My original plan was just to use the "-identify" flag and parse the log file.  This actually works really well up until I need to truncate the log file to keep it from getting too large. As soon as my truncating script is run, MPlayer stops writing to the log file:

```
FILENAME=/home/tc/mplayer.log
MAXCOUNT=100
if [ -f "$FILENAME" ]; then
    LINECOUNT=`wc -l "$FILENAME" | awk '{print $1}'`

    if [ "$LINECOUNT" -gt "$MAXCOUNT" ]; then
        REMOVECOUNT=`expr $LINECOUNT - $MAXCOUNT`
        sed -i 1,"$REMOVECOUNT"d "$FILENAME"
    fi
fi
```

I have searched and searched but have been unable to find any other way of getting the current playing file that works.

I have tried piping the output to another named pipe and then monitoring it, but only works for a few seconds, then MPlayer completely freezes.

I have also tried using bash (instead of ash) and piping the output to a function like the following, but get the same freezing problem:

```
function parseOutput()
{
    while read LINE
    do
        echo "get_file_name" > /tmp/mplayer-in
        if [[ "$LINE" == *ANS_FILENAME* ]]
        then
          echo ${LINE##ANS_FILENAME=} > "$CURRENTFILEPATH"
        fi
        sleep 1
    done

}

# START MPLAYER
mplayer -fixed-vo -nolirc -vc ffmpeg12vdpau,ffh264vdpau, -playlist $NEWPLAYLIST -loop 0 -geometry 1696x954 -slave -idle -input file=/tmp/mplayer-in -quiet | parseOutput &
```

I suspect I am missing something very obvious here, so any help, ideas, points in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

fodder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I gave up on getting the track from MPlayer itself.

My 'solution' is probably too hackish, but works for my needs since I know my machine will only ever have one instance of MPlayer running:

```
lsof -p $(pidof mplayer) | grep -o "/path/to/my/assets/.*"
```

If anyone has a better option I'm certainly still interested in doing this the right way, I just couldn't make any of the methods work.

fodder

Comment: I use a slightly different version which does not require to know the assets path in advance, prints just the filename: `lsof -p $(pidof -s mplayer) 2>/dev/null | grep -E "[0-9]+r.*REG" | grep -oE "[^/]+$"`. The first grep selects a regular file (REG) open with read permissions ([0-9]+r) from the output of `lsof` and the second one extracts the filename from the matching line.

Answer (score 2):

Alright then, so I'll post mine too.

Give this one a try (assuming there is only one instance running, like on fodder's machine):

```
basename "$(readlink /proc/$(pidof mplayer)/fd/* | grep -v '\(/dev/\|pipe:\|socket:\)')"
```

This is probably the safer way, since the file descriptors might not always be in the same order on all systems.
However, this *can* be shortened, with a little risk:

```
basename "$(readlink /proc/$(pidof mplayer)/fd/*)" | head -1
```

You might probably like to install this, too:
http://mplayer-tools.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `run` command.

Put this in `~/.mplayer/input.conf`:

```
DEL run "echo ${filename} ${stream_pos} >> /home/knarf/out"
```

Now if you press the delete key while playing a file it will do what you expect i.e. append the current file playing and the position in the stream to the `~/out` file. You can replace `echo` with your program.

See [slave mod docs](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/DOCS/tech/slave.txt) for more info (Ctrl-F somevar).

Answer (score 0):

About getting properties from MPlayer

I have used a non-elegant solution, but it is working for me.

```
stdbuf -oL mplayer --slave --input=file=$FIFO awesome_awesome.mp3 |
{
while IFS= read -r line 
    do
    if [[ "${line}" == ANS_* ]]; then
        echo "${line#*=}" > ${line%=*}  # echo property_value > property_name
    fi
    done
} & 
mplayer_pid=&!

read filename < ./ANS_FILENAME
read timeLength < ./ANS_LENGTH

echo ($timeLength) $filename
```

and so on..

It is in another proccess, that's why I've used files to bring properties

'stdbuf' is for not to miss anything

Answer (score 0):

I started putting together a bash library to handle tasks like this. Basically, you can accomplish this by dumping the mplayer output to a file. Then you grep that dump for "Playing " and take the last result with tail. This should give you the name of the file that's currently playing or that last finished playing.

Take a look at my bash code. You'll want to modify the `playMediaFile` function to your needs, but the `getMediaFileName` function should do exactly what you're asking. You'll find the code on [my github](https://github.com/nbros652/mplayer-status).